# Tagging Video Frames with GPS Coordinates

Tags: .net, video

Aside from using a hardware video encoding/decoding device, is there an easy was to capture frames from streaming videos and tag each frame with the current GPS coordinates?

Assume I am using windows, and I have the GPS coordinates sent in via USB and the camera is hooked up also. Any api or framework available for this?

Comment: How do you want to tag the frames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DirectShow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd390351(VS.85).aspx) to grab the frames - there are many examples available like this [CodeGuru post](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/g-m/directx/directshow/article.php/c9551/).